# Apparmor full system implementation help

Tags: 18.04, security, secure-boot, apparmor

I am trying to implement Apparmor full system implementation on Ubuntu Bionic in AWS EC2 instances.
https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/-/wikis/FullSystemPolicy#distribution

My goal is employ a deny-all, permit-by-exception policy to allow the execution of authorized software programs on the system.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Following the link, I am not able to do profile init-systemd /lib/systemd/** because udevd and timesyncd disrupts the boot up process and box fails to reboot. So I have individually captured everything in /lib/systemd and added it to
   /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/apparmor file.

`echo "profile init-systemd /lib/systemd/systemd-logind flags=(complain) {}" | /sbin/apparmor_parser -a`

`echo "profile lib-systemd-systemd-journald /lib/systemd/systemd-journald flags=(complain) {}" | /sbin/apparmor_parser -a`

`echo "profile init-systemd /lib/systemd/systemd flags=(complain) {}" | /sbin/apparmor_parser -a`

What can I do for udevd and timesyncd? How can I include them and still get a functioning box.

Secondly, right now I am passing empty profiles in `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/apparmor`. What is the best way to identify the permissions I should be giving in the profiles to achieve my goal?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can start by creating profiles in complain mod for `udevd` and `timesyncd` this way you can log violations without actually enforcing.

first we create the profiles

```
sudo touch /etc/apparmor.d/lib-systemd-udevd
sudo touch /etc/apparmor.d/lib-systemd-timesyncd
```

then edit them `sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/lib-systemd-udevd` add those lines

```
#include <tunables/global>

/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd flags=(complain) {

}
```

then reload the profiles and set the complain mod:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r -C /etc/apparmor.d/lib-systemd-udevd
sudo apparmor_parser -r -C /etc/apparmor.d/lib-systemd-timesyncd
```

then reboot and just check the logs `sudo journalctl -b | grep apparmor`

You can do the same to identify required permissions for other profiles.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. In attempt one, I left the `init-bottom/apparmor` un touched & created profile for udevd in apparmor.d dir, reload the profiles and did a reboot. Post reboot I grepped for apparmor in journald but nothing related to udev showed  up, there were several messages for journald comm=systemd-journal. So I added profile lib-systemd-systemd-journald in complain mode, updated initramfs. Added blank profile in apparmor.d dir too and rebooted. Post reboot, several messages for journald, tried using aa-logprof to augment the profile in apparmor.d but no success.